# How to have unauthenticated endpoints with Spring Boot Resource Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application annotated with `@ResourceServer`. I am trying to have unauthenticated endpoints as well as authenticated endpoints in my application, however all the endpoints return the same 401 response.

My SecurityConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/search").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
    }

}
```

But when I send a POST request to `/api/search` I get this response:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I also tried having only `anyRequest().permitAll()` in my SecurityConfig, but it still returns the same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pretty noobie mistake. I was actually configuring a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`.